# SSIS Package generation using BIMLC.EXE programatically using c#

Tags: ssis, biml

While generating SSIS packages using bimlc.exe using c# I'm getting ado.net connection error, it is giving error as could not create managed connection manager, I tried to release the connection and  change the connection and acquire it back again still it is getting the same error like below:

```
cm.ReleaseConnection(null);
cm.ConnectionString = "Data Source=*****;User ID=****;Password=******;Initial Catalog=****;Persist Security Info=****;Integrated Security=*****;";
cm.AcquireConnection(null);
```

Don't know where the error exists.

Comment: what's the error message?

Comment: Do you have a license for BimlStudio?